Prediction with a factor
I am confused with doing multiple linear regression with a factor in R. A is the binary variable, coded as 1 and -1 as a factor in lm. So, when making a prediction, how do we treat A=-1 with the coefficient, which is for A=1? I tried to figure out the fitted values for the first five obs, but it seems predict and my calculation don't result the same. What mistake did I make here?
set.seed(1)
expit <- function(x) 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
n <- 10000
X1 <- rnorm(n)
A <- 2*rbinom(n, 1, expit(X1))-1
X2 <- rnorm(n)
Y <- X1 + X2 + A*X1 + rnorm(n)
mydata <- data.frame(X1, A, X2, Y)

mydata$A <- as.factor(mydata$A)

mod <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + as.factor(A) + as.factor(A):X1)

predict(mod, newdata = mydata[1:5,])


-0.2107963  0.2664868 -0.4601201  2.5115522 -0.1143373

coef(mod2)[1] + coef(mod2)[2]*mydata[1:5,"X1"] + coef(mod2)[3]*mydata[1:5,"X2"] + coef(mod2)[4]*as.integer(mydata[1:5,"A"]) + coef(mod2)[5]*as.integer(mydata[1:5,"A"])*mydata[1:5,"X1"] 


-1.4523706  0.6258031 -2.1150596  5.6605056  0.5332321


Be careful with calling lm without a data argument. Otherwise, R will take all variables from the global environment.

I think the modelling process converts factors to dummy variables (0/1), which is why your computation doesn't give the correct answer. The coefficients for a factor variable compare each successive level to a reference level (by default, treatment contrasts), so use a logical (==1) to obtain the same values from the predict function.
mod2 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + as.factor(A) + as.factor(A):X1)

p1 <- predict(mod2, newdata = mydata[1:5,])
p2 <- coef(mod2)[1] + coef(mod2)[2]*mydata[1:5,"X1"] + 
  coef(mod2)[3]*mydata[1:5,"X2"] + 
  coef(mod2)[4]*as.integer(mydata[1:5,"A"]==1) + 
  coef(mod2)[5]*as.integer(mydata[1:5,"A"]==1)*mydata[1:5,"X1"] 

> all(p1==p2)
# [1] TRUE


As an aside, it's good practice to include the data argument when running models. And since you already converted A to a factor before running the model, you could have easily typed:
mod2 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + A + A:X1, data=mydata)

and obtained the same results.
Another observation is that A + A:X1 is equivalent to A*X1.

Why does mod <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + A + A:X1), yielding Error: variable 'A' was fitted with type "numeric" but type "factor" was supplied, even though A is a factor, is this a bug?

@jay.sf The error occurs after running predict probably because you did not specify data=mydata in the lm call. So R is taking the A from the globalEnv, not mydata.  There's no error in the OP's code because he converted A to a factor within the lm call.

You're right, data= was not used, we shouldn't blindly copy-paste, thanks!

Upvote but you don't even need as.integer, R will coerce the logical values to integer automatically.

Yes @RuiBarradas, that's another observation of the OP's code that I was going to make, but I didn't want to overload my answer with too many (irrelevant?) observations!
